# Visual Studio variable bin directory

Tags: visual-studio, build-process

I have a few VS 2010 C# projects that are shared between several solutions. I would like these  projects to build to the directory of the solutions they are open in. How do I do this?

I considered setting up different build configurations (Debug_Xsln, debug_Ysln, Release_Xsln...) but wasn't sure if there was a better way.

Comment: It is automatic when you add a reference to the project's output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42x5kfw4(v=VS.100).aspx

You can use a postbuild event with xcopy and the macro `$(SolutionName)` or `$(SolutionDir)` to copy the compiled files into the correct folder.

Go into properties for the project, build events tab, and in Post Build event command line enter something like this:

```
xcopy "$(ProjectDir)bin\$(ConfigurationName)\*.*" "$(SolutionDir)$(ProjectName)\bin\$(ConfigurationName)" /i /d /y
```

The benefit of this method is you can copy the build output of one project to multiple locations

OR

*(as Ziplin discovered)*

If you only have one location you want the build output to go, you can use the macros above to set the output path, like this:

```
$(SolutionDir)$(ProjectName)\bin\$(ConfigurationName)
```

just go to the project properties on the build tab and set your macroed location as the output path

Comment: One approach I have done when a group of libraries is shared among projects is to wrap them in a single solution and use xcopy to deploy them to a shared network location, then in each solution that uses them, it pulls from the shared location.  Then versioning can be controlled with subfolders, or each solution can always be automatically built with the latest version, depending on how you want to manage it.

Comment: Your answer looks much cleaner than my solution, thanks! Not so sure about your comment, however.

Comment: Josh, I found what I think is a cleaner way to do it. If you update you're answer, I'll give it to you because you led me the right way. - I can just set the output path to the text you gave -     <OutputPath>$(SolutionDir)bin\$(Configuration)</OutputPath>

Comment: I updated.  I didn't know macros worked in the output path.  Very cool, but the only caveat is that it will work for only one deployment location, where as the post build event is useful if you want to deploy to multiple locations or/while retaining the default output location.

Comment: Very true. I ran into an issue where I had VS register the assembly (A) with COM, and then xcopied as you had prescribed. When I rebuilt again, another assembly that referenced A tried to unregister it, but A had already been rebuilt to Av2, so the unregister step freaked out. Using the output path seemed like a better solution in this niche instance.